# Deleting same observations in two tables

Tags: stata

Let's say I have the following data:

Table 1 (My master dataset):

```
clear 
input str1 Name str9 (Day Time)   
 A     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"       
 A     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      
 B     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      
 B     24-Mar-08  "11:03:12"       
 B     24-Mar-08  "11:03:12"       
 C     25-Mar-08  "10:30:01"       
 D     25-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      
 D     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"       
 E     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"       
 F     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"       
 F     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"       
 F     25-Mar-08  "11:59:01"       
end
```

Table 2:

```
clear 
input str1 Insrument str9 (Day Time) float price  
 A     30-Mar-10  "09:29:34"  10    
 E     03-Mar-09  "08:23:19"  14   
 E     20-Mar-12  "12:15:11"  29    
 F     01-Mar-11  "10:30:01"  12     
end
```

I would like to remove the duplicate observations based on `name` variable from table 1. I open table 1 in Stata and need to introduce table 2 to Stata and then delete same observations which have same names in both tables, from table 1.

Finally, the result is:

```
+------+------------+----------+
| name |    date    |    time  |
+------+------------+----------+
| B    |  24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |
| B    |  24-Mar-08 | 11:03:12 |
| B    |  24-Mar-08 | 11:03:12 |
| C    |  25-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |
| D    |  25-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |
| D    |  25-Mar-08 | 11:13:59 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

The SQL code in SAS is:

```
proc SQL;
    create table table3 as
    select * from table1
    where name not in (select Instrument from table2);
quit;
```

How can I use this program using Stata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Keeping equities
rename name Instrument
merge m:1 Instrument using "file name path"
keep if _merge == 3
keep Instrument Day Time
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to do a merge on the names and keep only the ones that don't have a match:

```
clear 
input str1 Name str9 (Day Time)   
 A     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"       
 E     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      
 E     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      
 F     24-Mar-08  "11:03:12"       
end 

keep Name 
duplicates drop
tempfile names
save "`names'"

clear 
input str1 Name str9 (Day Time)   
 A     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"       
 A     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      
 B     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      
 B     24-Mar-08  "11:03:12"       
 B     24-Mar-08  "11:03:12"       
 C     25-Mar-08  "10:30:01"       
 D     25-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      
 D     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"       
 E     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"       
 F     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"       
 F     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"       
 F     25-Mar-08  "11:59:01"       
end 

merge m:1 Name using "`names'", keep(master) nogen
list, clean noobs
```

This yields:

```
Name         Day       Time  
   B   24-Mar-08   10:30:01  
   B   24-Mar-08   11:03:12  
   B   24-Mar-08   11:03:12  
   C   25-Mar-08   10:30:01  
   D   25-Mar-08   10:30:01  
   D   25-Mar-08   11:13:59
```

Comment: If variables in Table 2 and 1 are not the same, for example, Table 2 has other variables like 'Price', then what is the answer? While it is not necessary to add the price variable to Table 1.

Comment: I don't really follow your question. Can you modify your example with this case?

Comment: I am working on Table 1 and it is necessary to add Table 2 to Stata, which means my master dataset is table 1. For the difference between variables, please consider variable 'name' in table 2 is 'Instrument'.

Comment: You can modify the keep statement to include other variables, but you will need to add some logic about which observations to keep if those vary by name. If you add those other variables, they will be merged with table 1. You can also merge on name and date together. Don't try m:m merges; this is rarely what you want.

Comment: For better example the SQL code of this program in SAS is:
`proc SQL;
 create table table3 as
 select * from table1
 where name not in (select Instrument from Table2);
quit;`

Comment: That SQL is what my original code does. I still stand by my advice to modify your question with the scenario you have and the desired output.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitriy V. Masterov. I've modified my question.

Comment: Your edited question is still incomplete. You now need to add `rename Insrument Name` for the `merge` to work, but there is still no discussion of which price observation should be added to the final dataset. For example, for E, do you want price 14 or 29?

Comment: Table 1 is master and only the `instrument` variable requires from Table 2. In other words, the question is how to remove data of the `instrument` variable in Table 2 from Table 1?

Comment: This still does not make sense to me, so I cannot help. Best of luck!